# Transparency issue of area in area chart in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am facing a problem when i do a area chart through jasper.

The problem is that when multiple areas are there in the area chart section ,one is overrided by the next one.So the previous one is not visble.

It seems to be an issue of transparency of colours used.

below is piece of code

public class StatsChartCustomiser extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {

```
/** The class logger. */
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(StatsChartCustomiser.class);

public void customize(final JFreeChart jFreeChart, final JRChart jasperChart) {
    Plot plot = jFreeChart.getPlot();
    jFreeChart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer().getPlot().setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    jasperChart.getPlot().setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    if (plot instanceof CategoryPlot) {
        CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot) plot;
        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = categoryPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.red);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.green);
        categoryPlot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        categoryPlot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        categoryPlot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        categoryPlot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
        categoryPlot.getForegroundAlpha();
        CategoryAxis xAxis = categoryPlot.getDomainAxis();
        Font tickLabelFont = xAxis.getTickLabelFont();
        ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("Area Chart",jFreeChart);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        //frame1.setOpacity((float) .5);
        // category labels in category charts with lots of tick marks are
        // unreadable, so reduce font size (think a JFreeChart bug)
        xAxis.setTickLabelFont(tickLabelFont.deriveFont(8f));
        ValueAxis yAxis = categoryPlot.getRangeAxis();
        xAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 2.0)); // vertical
        yAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        jasperChart.getParentProperties();
        JRChartPlot jasperplot = jasperChart.getPlot();
        System.out.println("before----    "+jasperplot.getForegroundAlpha());
        jasperplot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
        System.out.println("after----    "+jasperplot.getForegroundAlpha());
        jasperplot.getForegroundAlpha();


    } else if (plot instanceof XYPlot) {
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) plot;
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        xyPlot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        xyPlot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        ValueAxis xAxis = xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        yAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        xAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        if (xAxis instanceof DateAxis) {
            DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) xAxis;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            String interval = (String) getParameterValue("Interval");
            if ("Day".equals(interval)) {
                sdf.applyPattern("HH:mm");
                // strange, but the range seems to comes out wrong for Day (comes out as 23:00 - 01:00 ???) unless explicitly set
                String fromDateString = (String) getParameterValue("FromDate");
                DateFormat dfdt = new SimpleDateFormat(Bof2Constants.CALENDAR_WIDGET_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
                // set hours,min,sec to 0 in FromDate to get the start time for the x axis
                try {
                Date fromDate = dfdt.parse(fromDateString);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(fromDate);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                Date startOfDay = cal.getTime();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
                Date endOfDay = cal.getTime();  
                dateAxis.setRange(startOfDay, endOfDay);
                SegmentedTimeline timeline = new SegmentedTimeline(Bof2Constants.MILLISECS_IN_AN_HOUR, 24, 0);
                timeline.setStartTime(fromDate.getTime() - 1);
                dateAxis.setTimeline(timeline);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to parse fromDateString:" + fromDateString + " for StatsChartReport by Day");
                }
            }
            int tickInterval = ((Integer) getParameterValue("TickInterval")).intValue();
            int tickIntervalCount = ((Integer) getParameterValue("TickIntervalCount")).intValue();
            dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(tickInterval, tickIntervalCount, sdf));
            dateAxis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ![jfreechart frame image transparency is present][1]


![PDF image, when chart embed with jasper area is not transparent][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dWWoF.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gadfz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely a PDF issue than it is a JFreeChart one. Charts are rendered on a canvas  using a  `Graphics2D` object, and if the underlying graphics engine (JasperReports in your case) does not handle the alpha channel correctly **or** the canvas is rasterized before rendering to PDF, there will not be any transparency.

This happens *probably* because JasperReports doesn't handle alpha channels the way JFreeChart would expect.